# Routing default gateway for 2nd vlan over a tunnel (linux/tinc)

Tags: linux, networking, tunneling, tinc

Fixed:
It turned out to be a combo of what BatchyX said (missing the 172.16.101.0/24 route on the remote end), and tinc on the remote side failing to run a -up script (the script wasn't executable).

So now everything works super, thanks for the help everyone :)

=============================================================================

My problem is surprisingly difficult to explain, so I'll break it up into smaller pieces, sorry in advance for the long text :)

I have a server at a hosting provider, that has a public ip, this server is running tinc (vpn software).

At home I have two vlans, VLAN1 (my normal subnet for pc's etc, sitting behind NAT), and VLAN20, for my vmware lab. environment.

What I would like to set up, is so that my VLAN20 network, can use the server at the hosting provider as its gateway (its external ip), instead of the external gateway I have at home.

For that I have a server at home, that has two network interfaces, one nic on VLAN1, and one nic on VLAN20.

Lets say I have the following ips:

```
Server at hosting provider:
Public IP: 123.123.123.123 (eth0)
Private IP: 10.1.0.1/24  (tun0)

Network at home:
VLAN1 - 192.168.1.0/24  (.1 is the gateway)
VLAN20 - 172.16.101.0/24

Network on server at home:
NIC1 (VLAN1) - 192.168.1.50/24 (eth0)
NIC2 (VLAN20) - 172.16.101.1/24 (eth1)
Tunnel - 10.1.0.2/24 (tun0)
```

I have set up tinc, so that my server at home works over the tunnel, I can ping 10.1.0.1 from the server at home, and 10.1.0.2 from the server at the hosting provider.

In addition to this I have set up so the server at home uses the tunnel for the default gateway, this all works from the actual server at home, my problem is that I cant get clients on the VLAN20 network to access the internet.

So the problem I have is that I cant figure out how to set up routing so that the 172.16.101.0/24 network uses the default gateway on the tunnel.

The routes on the server at home are these:

```
root@home:/etc/tinc/vpn/hosts# ip route
0.0.0.0/1 dev tun0  scope link
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
10.1.0.0/24 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.0.2
123.123.132.123 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
128.0.0.0/1 dev tun0  scope link
172.16.101.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.101.1
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.50
```

the /1's get added when the tunnel is up with:

```
ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 dev $INTERFACE
ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 dev $INTERFACE
```

Doing a traceroute from the server at home to 8.8.8.8:

```
root@home:/etc/tinc/vpn/hosts# traceroute -s 10.1.0.2 8.8.8.8 -n
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.1.0.1  33.681 ms  33.698 ms  33.658 ms
 2  Router_At_Hosting_Provider  34.930 ms  34.907 ms  34.875 ms
```

So the "tunnel" subnet (10.1.0.0) works fine with the default gateway over the tunnel.

This also works fine:

```
root@home:/etc/tinc/vpn/hosts# traceroute -s 172.16.101.1 10.1.0.2 -n
traceroute to 10.1.0.2 (10.1.0.2), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.1.0.2  0.032 ms  0.003 ms  0.005 ms
```

But my problem is this:

```
root@home:/etc/tinc/vpn/hosts# traceroute -s 172.16.101.1 8.8.8.8 -n
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
```

If anyone have any pointers to where I should be be looking, it would be really greatly appreciated.

(The full list of the changes done to both servers after a plain debian install, is here http://pastebin.com/r3Vsvycq)

Edit
I suck badly at Visio, but here's my attempt at showing what I'm trying to set up:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff2R6.png (cant put inline yet because my rep isn't high enough).

Comment: Is this thread going to be migrated (in this case i can post a solution here) or should i wait for a similar post in serverfault?

Comment: Just a bit puzzled from the 172.16.101.20/24 net i can ping 10.1.0.2 (so that part of the routing works)  and from 10.1.0.2 i can ping 8.8.8.8 (via the server on 10.1.0.1 across the tunnel), so that part also works, i just cant combine it, so the 172.16.101.0 can reach the internet through the 10.1.0.1 tunnel. And 172.16.101.20/24 cant ping 10.1.0.1 (far end of the tunnel), only the "same" end of the tunnel (10.1.0.2) works from 172.16.101.20/24. Must be missing something obvious :(

Comment: I think the problem is that the remote site does not have a route to 172.16.101.0/24 via the tunnel

Comment: Changed the routes on the box at home to what BatchyX said, and added a route on the remote server, that one can now ping 172.16.101.1, but not 172.16.101.100 which is a host behind the box at home on that network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several WTF in this configuration:

```
ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 dev $INTERFACE
ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 dev $INTERFACE
```

Help yourself and replace that by `ip route change default dev $INTERFACE`.  This will remove the default gateway on eth1 and replace it with your own. You might want to also set the prefered source address on that route, by adding `src 10.1.0.2` at the end.

If instead you want to keep the default route but add your own over it, then just change the metric of the original default route to 1 or more.  When you will add your default route, it will override (but not destroy) the original default route.

Also, the route to 10.1.0.0/24 when the VPN is up is a bit redundent, since it is already covered by the default route.

What you want as a routing table will look more like this:

```
default dev tun0 scope link src 10.1.0.2
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 metric 1
123.123.132.123 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
172.16.101.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.101.1
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.50
```

Now this routing table is correct.  The only problem now lies in your server do not have a route to 172.16.101.0/24 so will try to route that though its public interface.  The return path is essentially broken, so traceroute works but pings does not.

Just add a route at the remote site to 172.16.101.0/24 via tun0 and it will be good.

Comment: Thanks, the weird ip route stuff was mostly after i read: http://tinc-vpn.org/examples/redirect-gateway/

but changed it to what you said, and now i got the same route config as the one you listed, still no traffic flowing from 172.16.101.0/24 yet though, but must be getting closer.

Comment: Hitting a stone wall, have no idea what I should be googling, the only remaining thing to be done is having the vpn box at home sharing its "internet" (which is running via the tunnel on 10.1.0.0/24) on interface eth1 (172.16.101.1/24 net)

Comment: Seems to work now, did a lot of different route changes / tinc config changes, not sure which specific change did the trick, ill investigate tomorrow, and post findings.